# ElasticSearch boolean query to Solrj query

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, solrj, booleanquery

is there any tool or easy technique to migrate complex ES boolean query to Solr/ Solrj query.
I know kind of that `must => AND` `should => OR` needs to be changed.
Query sample here -

```
{
  "bool": {
    "must": [
      {
        "term": {
          "locale": {
            "value": "XXX",
            "boost": 1
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "terms": {
          "contentType": [
            "YYY",
            "ZZZ"
          ],
          "boost": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "terms": {
          "docId": [
            "ABC",
            "JKL"
          ],
          "boost": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "term": {
          "unPublished": {
            "value": false,
            "boost": 1
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "disable_coord": false,
    "adjust_pure_negative": true,
    "boost": 1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JSON Query DSL and compound queries](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_5/json-query-dsl.html#compound-queries).

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                "title:solr",
                "content:(lucene solr)"
            ],
            "must_not": "{!frange u:3.0}ranking"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so you mean I can directly pass my JSON boolean query in d parameter? But how can do the same in solrj?

Comment: I wanted something which can parse it into something like this would be great help -->  +title:solr +content:(lucene solr)